# How to align CSS dropdown menu to center?

Tags: html, css

I want to align my dropdown menu a tags to the center but can't figure out how to do that, only started with CSS recently.

It would display the dropdown dropdownbtn items in the dropdown-content with the links aligned to the center.

```css
.navbar {
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #333;
}

.navbar a {
  float: left;
  font-size: 16px;
  color: #f2f2f2;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.dropdown {
  float: left;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.dropdown .dropbtn {
  font-size: 16px;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  color: white;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  background-color: inherit;
  font-family: inherit;
  margin: 0;
}

.navbar a:hover,
.dropdown:hover .dropbtn {
  background-color: #ddd;
  color: black;
}

.dropdown-content {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #f9f9f9;
  min-width: 160px;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  z-index: 1;
}

.dropdown-content a {
  float: none;
  color: black;
  padding: 12px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
  text-align: left;
}

.dropdown-content a:hover {
  background-color: #ddd;
}

.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="navbar">
  <a href="#">Home</a>
  <div class="dropdown">
    <button class="dropbtn">Dropdown Menu</button>
    <div class="dropdown-content">
      <a href="#">Link 1</a>
      <a href="#">Link 2</a>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: Align the dropdown box to the center in relation to the dropdown button.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a `transform` on the dropdown.

```
  left: 50%;
  transform: translatex(-50%);
```

Also I switched from `float` to flexbox for simplicity and a more modern approach.

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

 ::before,
 ::after {
  box-sizing: inherit;
}

.navbar {
  background-color: #333;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

.navbar a {
  font-size: 16px;
  color: #f2f2f2;
  padding: 14px;
  
  text-decoration: none;
}

.dropdown {
  position: relative;
}

.dropdown .dropbtn {
  font-size: 16px;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  color: white;
  padding: 14px;
  background-color: inherit;
  font-family: inherit;
  margin: 0;
}

.navbar a:hover,
.dropdown:hover .dropbtn {
  background-color: #ddd;
  color: black;
}

.dropdown-content {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #f9f9f9;
  min-width: 160px;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  z-index: 1;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translatex(-50%);
}

.dropdown-content a {
  color: black;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
}

.dropdown-content a:hover {
  background-color: #ddd;
}

.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="navbar">
  <a href="#">Home</a>
  <div class="dropdown">
    <button class="dropbtn">Dropdown Menu</button>
    <div class="dropdown-content">
      <a href="#">Link 1</a>
      <a href="#">Link 2</a>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: What does the  ::before, ::after {box-sizing: inherit;} do?

Comment: It's just a part of my reset. Here it does nothing.

Comment: If I make the button in the html be an a tag the dropdown content overlaps with the navbar, how can I make it that the dropdown content only appears below the navbar?